# Javac не видит packages

Tags: java, maven

Написал программу, в которой подгружаю библиотеки с Maven.

Вот импорт:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder;
import com.google.code.geocoder.GeocoderRequestBuilder;
import com.google.code.geocoder.model.GeocodeResponse;
import com.google.code.geocoder.model.GeocoderRequest;
import com.google.code.geocoder.model.GeocoderResult;
```

Через Intellij IDEA всё отлично работает. Но мне нужно, чтобы программа запускалась из консоли. А там мне вылетает вот это:

```
C:\Users\yura9\IdeaProjects\Coordinates\src>javac Main.java
Main.java:4: error: package com.google.code.geocoder does not exist
import com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder;
                               ^
Main.java:5: error: package com.google.code.geocoder does not exist
import com.google.code.geocoder.GeocoderRequestBuilder;
                               ^
Main.java:6: error: package com.google.code.geocoder.model does not exist
import com.google.code.geocoder.model.GeocodeResponse;
                                     ^
Main.java:7: error: package com.google.code.geocoder.model does not exist
import com.google.code.geocoder.model.GeocoderRequest;
                                     ^
Main.java:8: error: package com.google.code.geocoder.model does not exist
import com.google.code.geocoder.model.GeocoderResult;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если либы подгружаются через Maven не надо использовать `javac`, используйте Maven для компиляции: https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить требуемые пакеты в classpath. Сделать это можно так:

```
javac -cp "lib/*" Main.java
```

Папка `lib` должна содержать все необходимые файлы других классов или jar пакетов.

---

Дополнительные материалы:

- [Управление Java classpath (Windows)](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-classpath-windows/)
- [Setting the Class Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: я их добавлял так: File->Project Structure->Libraries->From Maven. И так скачивалась библиотека. Как поместить их теперь в lib?

Comment: В зависимости от ОС и имени пользователя, библиотеки Maven должны быть в папке /home/${user}/.m2 или C:/Users/${user}/.m2 Они скрыты в системе. Их можно добавить в classpath таким же образом.

Comment: поместил jar файлы в папку libraries. Всеравно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло это 
`javac -cp .idea\libraries\geocoder-java-0.16.jar src\com\popivyv\coordinates\Main.java`

Закинул jar библиотеку в .idea\libraries\
Проект скомпилировался но теперь не могу запустить.

`java -cp .;.idea\libraries\geocoder-java-0.16.jar Main`

Выдает

`Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

Comment: Запускать нужно так: java -cp .;.idea\libraries\geocoder-java-0.16.jar com.popivyv.coordinates.Main